# Merging isn't working, when I merge two points it stretches to the middle, how do I stop this?

Tags: workflow, edit-mode

[image]

[image]

this is what happens as I try and do this, I don't know it is the character or if its something else, I really don't want to start the it again and would really like some help thanks
Thank You To everyone that answer I had made the hand on the mirrored side to it was trying to connect to the over side :)

Comment: it's the subsurf modifier smoothing the geometry, you should see a better result after you are done connecting the two parts

Comment: It could be that you select and try to join one vertex of real geometry and another - of generated with modifier (and hence not existing yet). Try disabling both modifiers in Edit mode and see what you can join.

Comment: turn off the mirror modifier momentarily (eye icon on the modifier) to figure out what the real geometrry is.